# Installing latest version of cgal in Ubuntu with apt-get

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, cgal

I'm trying to install the latest version of CGAL (i.e. CGAL 4.6.1) on a Linux Mint 13 Maya 64-bit machine. One of the features I'd like to use is the script called `cgal_create_CMakeLists`.

I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get install libcgal-dev
```

As listed in CGAL's website instructions. It works, but it seems to be installing an older version:

```
apt-cache policy libcgal-dev
libcgal-dev:
  Installed: 3.9-1build1
  Candidate: 3.9-1build1
  Version table:
 *** 3.9-1build1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/multiverse amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I've tried `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`, and uninstalling/reinstalling, but it keeps installing -what I think it is- an old version. If I look online, [libcgal-dev 3.9-1build1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/i386/libcgal-dev/3.9-1build1) seems to be from 2012, whereas 4.6.1 is more recent.

I've tried building from scratch, but I get to a dead end with some Qt related business that I'm not able to solve either, plus I have installed CGAL successfully, including the script I'm interested in, in a Ubuntu 14.04 machine this morning, so I can't figure out why the script I need is missing in this new installation test.

Comment: http://www.cgal.org/FAQ.html#debian_packages

Comment: Thanks! If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I don't understand how the link from Marc should be helpful. The `deb` commands are not found on my ubuntu machine.